# Delete a SVN branch locally but not from remote

Tags: svn

One of the branches in my SVN repo has grown a lot, and I am facing space problems in my local machine. I don't need this branch in my local copy, as I am working in a different one, but it should be kept in the repository. Is there a (safe) way to delete my local copy of the branch, not deleting it from the repository?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do not checkout from a root of a repository. Normally, your working copy should include only a certain branch, tag or trunk.
2. You can remove the branch locally using the means of your operating system. This branch will appear as Missing in your working copy, but it will not be removed from the repository.